# Hide Alt text when Hover

Tags: css

I have a DIV tag. Inside the DIV, I have a Table and in a row, I have placed a script code which displays random images which on a click leads to a url.

This is how the script renders inside the Div Tag

```
<div>  
<table>  
<tr>  
<td>  
<script />
<a href="some random url">
<img></img>
</a>
...
```

When the user hovers over these images, the anchor url shows as a message on browser status bar. This is very misleading for users. I want to know how to use CSS to hide this status message - Cross Browser and display a custom message instead. On the Div, I have given onmouseout and onmouseover, however it does not help.

Can this be done?

Comment: Rest assured that the majority of users never look down there, if they even have a browser that shows this text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.status :

> This property does not work in default configuration of Firefox and some other browsers: setting window.status has no effect on the text displayed in the status bar. To allow scripts change the the status bar text, the user must set the dom.disable_window_status_change  preference to false in the about:config screen.

This is a security feature that you can't realistically bypass.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: The intent of this feature is to (hopefully) prevent the site from displaying one URL in the status bar when hovering over a link, but then bring the user to a different URL when clicked. This feature is arguably misguided, as the same effect can be achieved using the click event with the default action suppressed, but that's beside the point.

Honestly, I don't think it's worth worrying about. Very few users are savvy enough to know to look at the status bar, much less understand what it says.

Comment: @rspeed: I really wish I could upvote your comment more than once. I mashed the mouse to no avail....

Answer (score 1):

common users dont know that they should look at that place in the browser window.

but you can hide that message... you can maybe just redirect with javascript
something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="someredirectfunction('someurl');return false;" >
 <img />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

onmouseout and onmouse over are used for events for client side scripting. Those are used "mostly" for a language called ecmascript(javascript). You unfortunately will not be able to do what you are asking with CSS, css is desinged to represent the appearance of a site, HTML the form, and javascript (other scripting sources) the function.